# find_by_sql or array issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having issues and I can't tell if it's with find_by_sql, something with the array object, or my logic. The following code is in a helper. This app has a coordinate grid with 4 quadrants. I replaced the app name with Something, so any references with that are to protect the app at the moment. I know this code may be convoluted, but I wanted to get it working first before anything else. Basically, the problem is this: When I run the SQL query, I get the results I expect back. When it hits coordinates that are children of the same parent, it'll draw one of them correctly, but when it gets to the delete, it will delete both coordinates from the array. If it makes a difference, the join table ids are getting returned as the parent coordinate's id. I tried selecting only what I needed, and that didn't help (as per the solution from this thread: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?415007-rails-join-creates-wrong-id). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To further elaborate, there are 16 parent coordinates in a quadrant. If it's blank, we draw a blank one (as per the first if), if it is not blank, we have to draw a div to collect all the children (first if of the else), then, we are supposed to be drawing all the children in there, and closing off the div and moving on. Hope this helps.

```
def buildQuadrantForUser(options={})
buffer=""

user_coordinates = SomethingUser.find_by_sql('
Select * from something_users
inner join coordinates as a on 
`something_users`.coordinate_id = `a`.id
inner join coordinates as b on
b.id = a.ancestry
Where ((user_id = '+options[:user].id.to_s+') AND (visibility = 2) AND (a.quadrant = '+options[:quadrant].to_s+')) 
Order By b.number ASC
')

i=0
while i<16 do
  i+=1
  first = true
  drawn = false
  l3num = 0
  user_coordinates.collect{|coor|
    puts "quadrant #{options[:quadrant].to_s}"
    if !coor.number.to_i.eql?(i)
      puts "quadrant: #{options[:quadrant].to_s}, number: #{i.to_s}, coordinate #{coor.id}"
      if drawn == false
        buffer<<"<div id=q"+options[:quadrant].to_s+"_"+i.to_s+" class='l2_div sc0'>" 
        buffer<<"</div>"
        drawn = true
      end
    else
      puts "quadrant: #{options[:quadrant].to_s}, number: #{i.to_s}, coordinate #{coor.inspect}"
      drawn = true
      if first == true
        buffer<<"<div id=q"+options[:quadrant].to_s+"_"+coor.number.to_s+" class='l2_div sc#{coor.coordinate.parent.percent_clicks_user_children(:user=>options[:user])}' data-value=#{coor.coordinate.parent.name} something-rating=#{coor.coordinate.parent.id.to_s}>"
        first = false
      end#end first
      l3num = l3num + 1
      if coor.coordinate.static?
        if !current_user.blank? && coor.user_id == current_user.id
          buffer<<content_tag(:div, content_tag(:span, "", :id=>'You'),:class=>"l3_#{l3num.to_s} cic#{coor.coordinate.percent_clicks_user(:user=>options[:user])}", :user=>'You', :somethingsomething=>coor.something_id.to_s,:something=>coor.something_id.to_s,:id=> "e" + coor.something_id.to_s, :rating=>coor.coordinate.name.to_s, :tag=>coor.something.tags.collect{|tag| tag.name+","}, :date=>time_ago_in_words(coor.updated_at), :source=>coor.something.url.split('/')[2], :link=>coor.something.url)
        else
          buffer<<content_tag(:div, content_tag(:span, "", :id=>coor.user.name),:class=>"l3_#{l3num.to_s} cic#{coor.coordinate.percent_clicks_user(:user=>options[:user])}", :user=>coor.user.name, :something=>coor.something_id.to_s,:id=> "e" + coor.something_id.to_s, :rating=>coor.coordinate.name.to_s, :tag=>coor.something.tags.collect{|tag| tag.name+","}, :date=>time_ago_in_words(coor.updated_at), :source=>coor.something.url.split('/')[2], :link=>coor.something.url)
        end
      else
        l3num = l3num-1 if l3num !=0
        if !current_user.blank? && coor.user_id == current_user.id
          buffer<<content_tag(:div, content_tag(:span, "", :id=>'You'),:class=>"l3_5 cic#{coor.coordinate.percent_clicks_user(:user=>options[:user])}", :user=>'You', :user=>coor.something.title,:something=>coor.something_id.to_s,:id=> "e" + coor.something_id.to_s, :rating=>coor.coordinate.name.to_s, :tag=>coor.something.tags.collect{|tag| tag.name+","}, :date=>time_ago_in_words(coor.updated_at), :source=>coor.something.url.split('/')[2], :link=>coor.something.url)
        else
          buffer<<content_tag(:div, content_tag(:span, "", :id=>coor.user.name),:class=>"l3_5 cic#{coor.coordinate.percent_clicks_user(:user=>options[:user])}", :user=>coor.something.title, :something=>coor.something_id.to_s,:id=> "e" + coor.something_id.to_s, :rating=>coor.coordinate.name.to_s, :tag=>coor.something.tags.collect{|tag| tag.name+","}, :date=>time_ago_in_words(coor.updated_at), :source=>coor.something.url.split('/')[2], :link=>coor.something.url)
        end
      end#end static
    buffer<<"</div>"
    puts "deleting #{coor.inspect}"
    user_coordinates.delete(coor)
    end#end coordinate.number = i.to_s
  }

end#end while
return buffer
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this fixed after a few more hours of work by restricting all ids from being selected. I ended up not deleting anything and had to restructure a lot of that code. For those trying to figure out the weird IDs in their join, definitely restrict what you're selecting.

Answer (score 2):

`Array#delete` removes any objects that are equal to the argument you give it.

For Active Record objects, equality is defined as having the same id.

You are doing `select *` but active record doesn't see `table1.id`, `table2.id` etc. - the columns shadow each other so when you too `coor.id` you'll get one of the id columns from the result set.

Given that this is what defines equality, that's obviously a bad thing - say for example that active record arbitrarily picked `b.id` to be its id, then when you remove that row from the array you'll remove every row where `b.id` had that value. I'm guessing you've been playing around with what you select, unless you select something such that each object has a different id `Array#delete` won't play ball

Also, you really shouldn't modify a collection while you are iterating over it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really sure what to do. I figured it was a combination of the two issues. I know I'll have to iterate over both the 16 and the collection so I figured removing from the collection would help speed things up. I tried using delete.at(0) because the current object is always there, but that still doesn't work for me. Any other ideas? How to fix the id, how to fix the deletion? I've been breaking my head against this for the past few days.

Comment: I changed the select to  Select something_users.*, a.name, a.ancestry, b.id as sid,  b.name, b.number from something_users. I am now getting the right ID, but it's still deleting two objects at once

Comment: why do you need to delete at all?

Comment: So it doesn't have to reiterate through as long a collection?